# Complex Type not found

Tags: c#, entity-framework, t-sql

So, I included a Stored Proc in my EF ORM. I added the SP to EF by doing `Import Function`. I chose to create a `Complex Type` from the SP columns, `FolderColumn`. After selecting `Run Custom Tool` the SP was added to my entity's context `cs` file:

```
    public virtual ObjectResult<FolderColumn> GetColumnFolderModel(Nullable<long> caseid, Nullable<long> folderid, Nullable<long> userid)
    {
        var caseidParameter = caseid.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("caseid", caseid) :
            new ObjectParameter("caseid", typeof(long));

        var folderidParameter = folderid.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("folderid", folderid) :
            new ObjectParameter("folderid", typeof(long));

        var useridParameter = userid.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("userid", userid) :
            new ObjectParameter("userid", typeof(long));

        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<FolderColumn>("GetColumnFolderModel", caseidParameter, folderidParameter, useridParameter);
    }
```

I see the entity in the Context Model:

[image: Complex Type is in the Context Model]

And editing my Context.edmx with the XML editor I found:

```
    <ComplexType Name="FolderColumn">
      <Property Type="Int64" Name="id" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Type="String" Name="Display" Nullable="false" MaxLength="256" />
      <Property Type="String" Name="Name" Nullable="false" MaxLength="256" />
      <Property Type="String" Name="Width" Nullable="true" MaxLength="12" />
      <Property Type="Boolean" Name="Sortable" Nullable="true" />
      <Property Type="String" Name="Align" Nullable="true" MaxLength="48" />
      <Property Type="Boolean" Name="Hide" Nullable="true" />
    </ComplexType>
```

under the `<Schema>` tag, along with my common Entity Types.

What I don't see is the Complex Type, `FolderColumn` in the `Context.cs`. And, more importantly, the Complex Type is not mapped to the entity, such that I cannot do:

```
BriefcaseEntities context = new BriefcaseEntities();
context.FolderColumn // <--- Not part of the context
```

and any reference to `FolderColumn` throws

> `The type or namespace name 'FolderColumn' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Why is my new Complex Type not part of my Context entities?

Answer (score 0):

A Complex Type represents something structured, but not stored. Entities are all stored in tables; Complex Types can come back from SPs, views, etc. So it's what I'd expect to see.

Comment: But I can't reference it. For example, at the SP in question, defined as: `public virtual ObjectResult<FolderColumn> GetColumnFolderModel(Nullable<long> caseid, Nullable<long> folderid, Nullable<long> userid) {}` throws an error: `The type or namespace name 'FolderColumn' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`.

Comment: Np. I realized that the Question was unclear. I updated the Question.